# C/C++ static function vs non-static function impact on linking time

Tags: c++, c, function, static, linker

The functions are usually declared non-static because they may be called in other object files.

I'm just curious if having

- several functions defined and used only in the source file,
- having many source files of this type and
- declaring those functions static instead of non-static,

it would improve the linking time. Is it worth making them static if are only used and defined in same source file?

Comment: Yes. Not only because of linking times, but also because of ODR.

Comment: It would reduce the size of symbol tables and the number of fixups, simplying the linker's job.  The improvement in link time is unlikely to be worth the effort of changing the source code.

Comment: As a general rule, I would say functions and other symbols are best defined static or made "invisible" by default. If it's necessary to reference them externally, this warrants a promotion to non-static or visible. This is not so much for improving the linking time, but for improving stability of the (internal or external) API.

Comment: Instead of declaring internal functions `static` use an unnamed `namespace` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces  _"...Unnamed namespaces as well as all namespaces declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace have internal linkage,..."_

Comment: @Cheatah Well API separation is another topic.

Comment: You might want to remove the `C++` tag in the question - `static`means an entirely different thing in C than in C++.

Comment: @tofro It is about function visibility and the impact of function visibility data on linking time. There there is no difference between C and C++ regarding the visibility of static functions. Static methods in C++ is another thing.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is defined and used in a single source file, it should always either be static, or defined in an anonymous namespace. This is because you risk violating ODR. Also, this allows the compiler to completely remove the function from the binary if it can be inlined everywhere. This is not possible for non-static functions.

About linking times, you should probably profile that.

Comment: The linking time is the point here. In huge projects taking hours to be built, it would be very hard to profile because changing the static qualifier in every case is unfeasible. In small projects perhaps the difference between linking times is insignificant.

Comment: @Flaviu insignificant, but measurable, right? It shouldn't be too difficult to create a moderately sized benchmark (perhaps generated by a script) to get the general idea.

Comment: Generating many source files with many functions that only will print something, it's a good idea. Could be done.